# excel 2013 customize context shapes and shapes group menu right click

Tags: xml, excel, vba

i modified my context shapes menu, editing a xml file to hide all item and add my commands. I used excel idmso ids to this. I dowloaded thm from web. Itemsseems to be the same for excel 2010 and 2013. But for excel 2010 it work well. If i use the same xml, with the same idmso in excel 2013 it works for every items but i foun three new ones in shape context menu:Style to edit shape style, Fillin to fill shape with different color, texture etc and the last for border. I'm looking for right idmso to hide them. can anyone help me ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ShowMenuFloaties = True
```

This line of VBA will get rid of what you speak of.